# Will an ACS 13T X 3/32 Crossfire freewheel fit an All-City Standard 130mm Hub?

Tags: parts, single-speed, freewheel

Will an ACS 13T X 3/32 Crossfire freewheel fit an All-City Standard 130mm fixed/free Hub?   I am attempting to setup a goldsprints setup using a very large front ring and a small rear freewheel. I'm not sure whether a freewheel this small will thread on to these hubs.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but instead of using a freewheel hub, you could use a cassette hub and simply run the chain around a single 11t sprocket.  You'd have to adjust for chainline in the front.

Comment: I found the following on acsbmx.com:

All ACS freewheels feature chromoly sprockets with 4 pawls (2 pairs engaging alternately), for quick engagement. ACS 16T - 22T freewheels thread on Standard English hub threads, and remove with the ACS universal removal tool.
 
"All ACS 14T and 15T freewheels thread onto smaller, metric 'BMX Flip-Flop' threads, and are removed with the ACS 14T removal tool.  You may need to remove your hub axle for the tool to have clearance.   ACS hubs have a slide-off shoulder to give the tool necessary clearance.

Comment: So it looks like the smallest I can use is 16T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only 16T through 22T ACS freewheels use english threading found on the all city hubs.

Comment: [Adventure Components](http://www.adventurecomponents.com/freewheels.htm) (AC, not ACS) makes (or made?) a 15t freewheel that threads onto a standard 1.37" x 24 hub.  I use it on my folding bike with 20" wheels.  The bearing design means it has a fair amount of slop, but it is pretty cheap.

Comment: It appears that the 15t freewheel still exists and is available on amazon. http://www.amazon.com/Adventure-Components-AC-15T-FREEWHEEL/dp/B003CMQ8B8

Answer (score 2):

No. Freewheels that small use a smaller diameter thread intended for BMX hubs. The smallest freewheel you're going to find for that hub is a 15T. I believe ACS makes one in 15T called Claws that fits a standard hub. Cheap and it works.